# Simple quiz issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, checkbox

I'm trying to build a basic one question quiz. Based on the checkboxes checked 1 of 3 result divs should show.

1. If consolidation *hasn’t* been checked then it should show the low results div
2. If *everything has* been checked then show the high results div
3. If consolidation has been ticked but *other items are unticked* then show medium results div

I also need to populate the medium results div with the names of the boxes that weren't checked on submit but I don't know how to go about it. Right now I've got it mostly working on submit but I can only get medium and low results to show, not the high results div. I think it's an issue with the priorities of the statements.

https://jsfiddle.net/lucym/azLf2s0t/3/

```js
var a = document.querySelector('#consolidation');
    var btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
    btn.onclick = () => {
      if (a.checked == false) {
        $('#low').show();
      } else if ($('#list :checkbox:not(checked)').length == 0) {
        $('#high').show();
    
      } else if (a.checked == true) {
        $('#medium').show();
    
      } else {
        alert('select an option');
      }
    };
```

```css
.results {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list" style="max-width: 650px; margin: 40px auto;">
        <!-- Consolidatation-->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="consolidation" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Searched and combined lost funds</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- Advice -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="advice" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Talked with an advisor</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- identity -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="identity" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Completed an ID check</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- balance -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="balance" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Checked your balance</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- app -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="app" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Downloaded the Sunsuper app</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- calculator -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="calculator" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Used our retirement calculator</label>
        </fieldset>
    
        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit">
    
        <!-- Result options -->
        <div id="low" class="results">low results</div>
        <div id="medium" class="results">medium results</div>
        <div id="high" class="results">high results</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: should be `$('#list :checkbox:not(:checked)')` with a `:` prefifx for checked also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `:` before `checked` `($('#list :checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)`:

```js
var a = document.querySelector('#consolidation');
    var btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
    btn.onclick = () => {
      if (a.checked == false) {
        $('#low').show();
        $('#high').hide();
        $('#medium').hide();
      } else if ($('#list :checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0) {
        $('#high').show();
        $('#medium').hide();
        $('#low').hide();

    
      } else if (a.checked == true) {
    mytext='<br> You have an average results, try doing :<br>';
        var unchecked = $('#list :checkbox:not(:checked)');
        for (i = 0; i < unchecked.length-1; i++) 
        mytext +=unchecked[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.innerText+', ';
        mytext+=unchecked[unchecked.length-1].nextSibling.nextSibling.innerText;
        mytext+=' to improve.';
        $('#medium').append(mytext);
        $('#medium').show(); 
    
      } else {
        alert('select an option');
      }
    };
```

```css
.results {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list" style="max-width: 650px; margin: 40px auto;">
        <!-- Consolidatation-->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="consolidation" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Searched and combined lost funds</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- Advice -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="advice" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Talked with an advisor</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- identity -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="identity" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Completed an ID check</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- balance -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="balance" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Checked your balance</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- app -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="app" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Downloaded the Sunsuper app</label>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- calculator -->
        <fieldset>
          <input id="calculator" type="checkbox" name="">
          <label>Used our retirement calculator</label>
        </fieldset>
    
        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit">
    
        <!-- Result options -->
        <div id="low" class="results">low results</div>
        <div id="medium" class="results">medium results</div>
        <div id="high" class="results">high results</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I've updated my js fiddle and its working great! Do you have any idea how to pull the unchecked item names into the medium results div? I want to use that space to say e.g. you have an average results, try doing a, b, c (unchecked items) to improve.

Comment: @Lucy I am unable to format this appropriately in a comment but you can basically do something like this (please unminify): `var unchecked = $('#list :checkbox:not(:checked)');
for (i = 0; i < unchecked.length; i++) {  
  mytext =  unchecked[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.innerText;
  $('#medium').append(mytext);
  $('#medium').show();
}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but I made an edit, run it.